# React fetch() overwriting data in textbox

Tags: reactjs, async-await, fetch-api

I'm currently learning ReactJS, so if I miss any fundamentals please let me know.

I've written a frontend using React that should **render out some markdown text** it gets **from an API**, however when running the **fetch request** it **runs multiple times** causing the **data populated** from the **original fetch** to be **changed/removed**

[image: console output from fetch]

how do I stop the fetch from pulling empty data after it's populated?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { useParams, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import DocumentLayout from "../components/DocumentLayout";
import ReactQuill from "react-quill";
import "react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css";

const EditDocument = () => {
  const params = useParams();

  let navigate = useNavigate;

  let [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  let [document, setDocument] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchDocument = async () => {
      const res = (
        await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8080/markdown?id=${params.id}`)
      )
        .json()
        .then((res) => setDocument(res));

      if (res.status === 404) {
        navigate("/");
      }
      setLoading(false);
    };
    fetchDocument();
  }, [params.id]);

  console.log(document);

  return loading ? (
    <h3>Loading...</h3>
  ) : (
    <DocumentLayout>
      <ReactQuill
        theme="snow"
        value={document?.markdown}
        onChange={(document) => setDocument(document)}
      />
      <button className="editor save-icon">Save</button>
    </DocumentLayout>
  );
};

export default EditDocument;
```

I've **looked at similar problems** on Stack Overflow, and **googled the issue**, but **most seem** to **address the async part** of the fetch and **not the multiple requests**.

I'm expecting to have one request and return one set of data.

Comment: `useEffect` runs twice in strict mode

Comment: @Konrad it shouldn't if `params.id` is identical

Comment: @mousetail it should. https://react.dev/learn/synchronizing-with-effects#how-to-handle-the-effect-firing-twice-in-development

Comment: @Konrad only in development. it's to catch problems like this so you know when you missed effect clean-up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple things to point out

1. mixing async..await with `.then` is cumbersome
2. you are fetching data without cleaning up and properly handling side effects

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchDocument = async () => { //
      const res = (
        await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8080/markdown?id=${params.id}`)
      )
        .json() // ❌ mix async..await with then
        // ❌ possible setState on unmounted component
        .then((res) => setDocument(res));

      if (res.status === 404) {
        navigate("/"); // ❌ no error communication
      }
      setLoading(false); // ❌ possible setState on unmounted component
    };
    fetchDocument();
    // ❌ no clean up
  }, [params.id]);
```

Here's how I would go about fixing it -

```js
// ✅ isolated, reusable api 
async function getMarkdown(id) {
  const res = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8080/markdown?id=${id}`)
  if (res.ok) return res.json()
  throw Error(`failed to get markdown: HTTP ${res.status}`)
}
```

Now your component's effect can focus solely on the parts it is responsible for. See the [fetching data guide](https://react.dev/learn/synchronizing-with-effects#fetching-data) from the React docs for more guidance -

```js
useEffect(
  () => {
    let mounted = true // ✅ local mounted state

    // ✅ no need to define a new function
    // ✅ only execute side effects like setState or navigate if mounted
    getMarkdown(params.id)
      .then(doc => mounted && setDocument(doc))
      .catch(err => mounted && navigate(`/?error=could-not-fetch`))
      .finally(() => mounted && setLoading(false))

    return () => {
      mounted = false // ✅ component unmounted
    }
  },
  [params.id]
)
```

Comment: Would it be better to abort the request?

Comment: @Konrad better? no, it's extra. `fetch` has an abort mechanism so you can do that *in addition* to the other cleanup here. however ordinary promises do not offer cancellation so you'll have to use the technique outlined in the guide.

Answer (score -2):

Here you should add checking block of params.id.
You could get undefined for that, and you need to fetch when it is number.

```
const fetchDocument = async () => {
  const res = (
    await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8080/markdown?id=${params.id}`)
  )
    .json()
    .then((res) => setDocument(res));

  if (res.status === 404) {
    navigate("/");
  }
  setLoading(false);
};

useEffect(() => {
  if (typeof params.id !== "undefined") fetchDocument();
}, [params.id]);
```